# If $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is continuous, then is $f$ Lebesgue-measurable?

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be continuous.

Then, is $f$ Lebesgue-measurable?

I know that if $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to {\mathbb{R}}$ is continuous, then $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable since for all $a\in \mathbb{R},$ $\{f>a\}=f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is open and thus Lebesgue-measurable.

But when the value of $f$ is in $\overline{\mathbb{R}},$ is $f$ Lebesgue-measurable? In this case, $\{f>a\}=f^{-1}((a,\infty])$ but I don't know whether this is Lebesgue-measurable or not.

Comment: $(a,\infty]$ is an open set in $\overline{\mathbb R}$, no?

Comment: It is Borel measurable, hence also Lebesgue measurable.